# How to right use "Pool" in parallel downloading files?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I want use a parallel downloading videos from youtube, but my code ending with exception "`PicklingError`". Can you help guys with code, how it should be, please.

Another fixed variant:

```
import sys
#from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pytube import YouTube
from youtubeMultiDownloader import UiMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog


class YouTubeInstance:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.youtube = YouTube
        self.path = path
        #self.ui_obj = ui_obj

    def download_file(self, url):
        self.youtube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution().download(self.path)
        #self.ui.ui.youtube_outputs.setText(f'Video \'{self.youtube.title}\' has been downloaded successfully!')


class YouTubeMultiDownloader(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pool = Pool
        self.ui = UiMainWindow()
        self.ui.setup_ui(self)
        self.path_to_dir = None
        self.urls = None

    def _get_urls_from_form(self):
        self.urls = self.ui.youtube_urls.toPlainText().split('\n')
        return len(self.urls)

    def choose_directory(self):
        self.path_to_dir = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))

    def run_multi_downloads(self):
        youtube = YouTubeInstance(self.path_to_dir)
        self.pool(self._get_urls_from_form()).map(youtube.download_file, self.urls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = YouTubeMultiDownloader()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Updated:**

My ui :)
[image: My ui]

Error 1 fixed:
[image: Error 1]

Error 2 fixed:
[image: Error 2]

Error 3 actual:
[image: Error 3]

Comment: Hi, please add error message completely and the line which error happened.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago added

Comment: Because you're trying to parallelize an instance method the entire object has to be serialized (pickled). This is often problematic. I would rewrite this so download_file is a standalone function with no weird scoping that can be easily serialized.

Comment: @CJR i rewrite my code and i get a new error, don't know what it is. In post screen and new code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the wrong side of the stick. Take a look at `multiprocessing` module documents. As it says, calling `Pool` method is for running multiple instance of same function simultaneously (in parallel). So call `Pool` method as many numbers you want, meanwhile your method does not any parameters, call it without any arguments:

```
with Pool(5) as p:
    print(p.map(YouTubeMultiDownloader))
```

It create 5 parallel instance. You can change the code an refine your errors.

Comment: i rewrite my code and i get a new error, don't know what it is. In post screen and new code added.

Comment: I think some object in your 'youtubevideodownliader' function is null or None type. Put a breakpoint in the first line of your method and trace it.Also remember set pool parameter to 1 then you can trace easier.

Comment: Yeah, i found it, and fixed, but i get a new error, oh my gosh :) Will add in post.

Comment: Think i need more gather information about urllib error, i think i know what's wrong.

Comment: Good luck. Your UI is interesting 